# Must declare the scalar variable "@id". Creating stored procedure with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a stored procedure for updating a table according to id given but it is showing me error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateCategoryPro
    (@categoryName VARCHAR(64),
     @IsActive BIT,
     @IsSelected BIT,
     @mediaId INT,
     @pageTitle VARCHAR(128),
     @metaKeyword VARCHAR(512),
     @metaDescription VARCHAR(256),
     @createDate DATETIME,
     @createdBy INT,
     @updatedDate DATETIME,
     @updatedBy INT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CategoryMaster 
    SET categoryName = @categoryName,
        @IsActive = IsActive,
        @IsSelected = IsSelected,
        @mediaId = mediaId, 
        pageTitle = @pageTitle,
        metaKeyword = @metaKeyword,
        metaDescription = @metaDescription,
        @createDate = createDate,
        @createdBy = createdBy,
        @updatedDate = updatedDate,
        @updatedBy = updatedBy
    WHERE categoryId = @id
END
```

Getting error at `@id`

Answer (score 1):

To validate your query result based on specific ID, you have to take it from the input of the procedure as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateCategoryPro
    @id int,
    @categoryName varchar(64),
    @IsActive bit,
    @IsSelected bit,
    @mediaId int,
    @pageTitle varchar(128),
    @metaKeyword varchar(512),
    @metaDescription varchar(256),
    @createDate datetime,
    @createdBy int,
    @updatedDate datetime,
    @updatedBy int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CategoryMaster 
    SET categoryName=@categoryName,
        IsActive = @IsActive,
        IsSelected = @IsSelected,
        mediaId = @mediaId, 
        pageTitle=@pageTitle,
        metaKeyword=@metaKeyword,
        metaDescription=@metaDescription,
        createDate = @createDate,
        createdBy = @createdBy,
        updatedDate = @updatedDate,
        updatedBy = @updatedBy
    WHERE categoryId = @id
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `@id` as part of your stored procedure parameters.

Comment: where should i put that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare and pass variable to stored procedure, Make sure you passing categoryid value as @id parameter to stored procedure. Below is updated stored procedure, added @id parameter.

```
create Procedure updateCategoryPro
(
@categoryName varchar(64),
@IsActive bit,
@IsSelected bit,
@mediaId int,
@pageTitle varchar(128),
@metaKeyword varchar(512),
@metaDescription varchar(256),
@createDate datetime,
@createdBy int,
@updatedDate datetime,
@updatedBy int,
@id INT
)
As
Begin
UPDATE CategoryMaster SET categoryName=@categoryName,@IsActive = 
IsActive,@IsSelected = IsSelected,@mediaId = mediaId, 
pageTitle=@pageTitle,metaKeyword=@metaKeyword,
metaDescription=@metaDescriptin 
,@createDate = createDate,@createdBy = createdBy,@updatedDate = 
updatedDate,@updatedBy = updatedBy
WHERE categoryId = @id
End
```